# Advance range sorting options not sorting in order for numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Something strange is happening with the sorting. I am sorting G (weight) from smallest to largest. The numbers are 1 to 41.

It doesn't sort starting from the number 1. Instead the order is 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,21,23,25,26,3,30,35,4,41,5,6,7,8,9.

I know technically 10 starts with the number one, but shouldn't this application be smart enough to know that you don't start counting at number 10? The smallest weight of 2 should be first, followed 3,4,5,67,8,9,10,11,12,etc.

Is this not possible with that sorting option?

Comment: It sounds like your Col-G weights are strings and not actual numbers. And assuming that is the case, Google sorts in order according to ASCII char numbers. If you have any non-numeric characters appended (e.g., "kg"), then you've created strings automatically. However, if you only have digits and they somehow got into your sheet as strings (which are *not* actively generated by formula), you can try selecting that column and choosing **Format > Number > 0**. Otherwise, please share a link to your sheet, as there isn't much more anyone will be able to tell you without seeing it.

Comment: Can believe I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Comment: We all have our moments. Since this seemed helpful, I posted it as a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

try to multiply your G column with 1 to convert your string numbers into numeric numbers as of, you are sorting it now by alphabetical order `10,1,20,2` not numerical `1,2,10,20`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Col-G weights are strings and not actual numbers. And assuming that is the case, Google sorts in order according to ASCII char numbers. If you have any non-numeric characters appended (e.g., "kg"), then you've created strings automatically. However, if you only have digits and they somehow got into your sheet as strings (which are not actively generated by formula), you can try selecting that column and choosing Format > Number > 0.